# Is it possible to get 2nd row (only) in a KQL query?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am querying a MS AI database using KQL.

I am sorting (desc) my records by timestamp.

While I can easily `take 1` to return the latest record (first row while sorting by timestamp), is it possible to take the second?

Is there a "skip" operator as in C# Linq?

using `take 2` will return both records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `row_rank_dense()` function of ADX you can get ranks of the records and then using `where` on extended *rank* column you can filter the nth record.

Please refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rowrankdensefunction) to read more about it.

Below is sample query with sample data.

```
datatable (timeStamp : datetime , str :string )
[
datetime("2023,03,13"),"aaa",
datetime("2023,03,14"),"bbb",
datetime("2023,03,15"),"ccc",
datetime("2023,03,11"),"ddd",
datetime("2023,03,16"),"eee",
datetime("2023,03,16"),"fff"
]
| order by timeStamp desc
| extend rank = row_rank_dense(timeStamp)
| where rank == 2
| project-away rank
```

**Result**

[image]